# Two riddles for two people

Tags: riddle

1:

Have a peak
take a swing
drink some soup
return a ring

2:

coming from a line of paper
although wrong, we named a vapor
launching animals: one, two, three
impressing royalty, who are we?

Comment: I have some ideas about this, but can you clarify if those are two unrelated riddles, each with one of the two people as the answer, or two parts of the same riddle, whose answer is a pair of people? Or something else entirely, that it's part of the riddle to figure out?

Comment: also the expression "have a peek" is usually spelled "peek" not "peak". Can you clarify if your spelling is intentional or just a typo/misspelling?

Comment: @BigBlackBox spelling is intentional. The answer is a pair of people, both riddles have the same answer as a check for the other one.

Comment: Has Teflon got anything to do with this question?

Comment: @BigBlackBox already has the answer - just needs to edit in the reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Okay, so the undeveloped idea that I initially thought was wrong turned out to be the right answer after all. I've now added the details.

The answer: the two people described in each of the two riddles are

> The **Montgolfier brothers**, inventors of the hot-air balloon.

Riddle 1:

> The phrase "Montgolfier brothers" is a combination of 
>  **Mont**: "peak" in "have a peak", 
>  **golf**: related to "swing" in "take a swing", 
>  **broth**: soup in "drink some soup", 
>  ers, or I guess the word **hers**, is sorta-kinda related to "ring" in "return a ring".

Riddle 2:

> "coming from a line of paper": as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgolfier_brothers) says, "The brothers were born into a family of paper manufacturers in Annonay, in Ardèche, France".
>  "although wrong, we named a vapor". Wikipedia says of Joseph, the older of the brothers, that, after observing the tendency of hot over a fire to rise, "He believed that contained within the smoke was a special gas, which he called Montgolfier Gas, with a special property he called levity."
>  "launching animals, one two three": Wikipedia writes of one of the brothers' first experimental hot-air balloon flights, "The king proposed to launch two criminals, but it is most likely that the inventors decided to send a sheep, a duck, and a rooster aloft first."
>  "impressing royalty, who are we?": the Montgolfier brothers invention astonished not just royalty but all of France, Europe and (I suspect) the world. In particular, Wikipedia writes that "... in December 1783, in recognition of their achievement, their father Pierre was elevated to the nobility and the hereditary appellation of de Montgolfier by King Louis XVI of France."

Comment: Another thought: "Impressing royalty" could also refer to the Nobel Prize, which is given out by the King of Sweden.

Comment: 'Have a peak' could also refer to the distinguishing features of the spectral lines

Comment: You are so close... in fact you have the right answer. The first riddle is a word-association to get their name. Oh... and the 'ring' clue is pretty terrible, sorry, it's all I could come up with (whose is it?).

Comment: Okay, very nice. Mont=peak, swing=golf. Thinking about the other ones...

Comment: Soup=French...?

Comment: Funnily enough, my other riddle you tried to solve was also about "launching animals", and you also proposed an answer with "golf". Coincidence...? ;-)

Comment: Hah, yes total coincidence. I hadn't even noticed that one was solved. It's possible that thinking about golf may have made me think of these two though.

Comment: Drink some soup = "Broth", return a ring = "hers", right?

Comment: The second part is all pretty self-explanatory when you read the Wikipedia page: Their father was a paper maker, Mongolfier gas was the vapor that Joseph believed has a special property called "levity". The last two @BigBlackBox nailed earlier

Answer (score 0):

Is it a volcano?

- A peak is obvious.
- Not sure about what "swing" would refer to.
- Drink some soup could be a pool of lava inside the volcano.
- Return a ring is either a reference to The Lord of the Rings, or perhaps referring to the ring around the tip of a stereotypical conical volcano.
- Coming from a line on paper refers to the fact that it appears on maps.
- Vapour is the smoke coming from the volcano.
- I'm not too sure about the last two lines, but any animals around when a volcano erupts would certainly be high tailing it out of there, and volcanoes are impressive in general.

Comment: No, the answer is a pair of people. Two real people who actually existed or exist. :)

Comment: If there is a lotr reference maybe the first charachter of the pair is Frodo, if anyone want to look on that have fun I can't seem to find anything for 2 that goes with Frodo

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer OP said they're real people who actually existed, so that would seem unlikely.

Comment: Yeah I was thinkin about Elijah wood (forgot his name while first commenting haha), should have precised that, the actor is real afterall, even if it seems unlikely it might be that :)

Comment: @jhabbott what do you mean "Two…people" Your comment above said "both riddles have the same answer".

Comment: @JimCullen it appears that both riddles are referring to the same two people.

Comment: @BigBlackBox oh, I see! There are two people, and *both* of them are named in *each* of the two riddles? As opposed to it being one person per riddle.

Comment: That's right, both riddles have the same pair as their answer. This is nothing to do with LoTR. I will add some hints.